# How to find source code of module I am importing

Tags: haskell, module

How do I find the source of the code I am importing. Like if I do

```
λ <Prelude>: import Graphics.EasyPlot 
λ <Prelude Graphics.EasyPlot>:
```

How do I find that code. I do not mean an online copy of the code (Google is very good at indexing Hackage by that) but where it is on my system that I can edit. The reason is that it is a bit buggy, and I want to try and fix it. (I might submit a patch, but I just want to fix it for my own use first.)

Comment: The code isn't necessarily on your system, you might just have an interface file and object file.

Comment: If you're going to submit a patch, it'd probably be best to do so through whatever version control system is used by the library's author(s), instead of modifying the code that might be installed to your system.  Usually this is with Git, Darcs, or Subversion.

Comment: I may not submit a patch, it will probably be some sort of hack. Also, I don't think it is an interface file since I know it is haskell code (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/easyplot-1.0/docs/src/Graphics-EasyPlot.html)

Comment: @PyRulez When you install it, it will be compiled to a binary file.

Answer (score 1):

As @ThomasDuBuisson mentioned, you many not necessarily find that on your system. One thing which I generally do is fetch it using cabal:

```
cabal fetch package-name
```

It downloads the tarballs of the package. Once you have fetched it, the entire source will be under the path where cabal puts it. In my case, it is (`/home/sibi/.cabal/packages/hackage.haskell.org/package-name` ). You can then untar and then build it from the cabal file which is already present there.

That being said you should probably using the version control system which the project is using as @bheklilr pointed out.

Comment: You can also use `cabal unpack <pkg>` (older cabal) or `cabal get <pkg>` (newer cabal versions) to unpack in a subdirectory of the current directory